# JAVA Clipboard (copy,paste,cut) How To; Most Efficiently

Tags: java, swing, clipboard

Looking over  lot of examples that are sometimes helpful and other times are not I would like to ask the community what is the most efficient way of creating the Clipboard that has cross application capabilities in the sense copy& paste from the browser to app. and vice versa. I was looking at some of the examples out there and it seems everyone kind of has their own way of doing it, just curious on the methods you guys had the most success with that is short and does whats needed, thanks.

Should this not work? userField is my JTextArea and my class is implementing MouseListener

```
  public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {}
  public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}
  public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}

  public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {


        }

    @Override
 public void mousePressed(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
     userField.addMouseListener(this);
                int modifiers = mouseEvent.getModifiers();
                if ((modifiers & InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK) == InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK) {
                    System.out.println("Left ");
                }
                if ((modifiers & InputEvent.BUTTON2_MASK) == InputEvent.BUTTON2_MASK) {
                    System.out.println("Middle ");
                }
                if ((modifiers & InputEvent.BUTTON3_MASK) == InputEvent.BUTTON3_MASK) {
                    System.out.println("Right button is being real naughty");
                }


        };
```

Comment: *"it seems everyone kind of has their own way of doing it"* I'd trust [Drag and Drop and Data Transfer: Adding Cut, Copy and Paste (CCP)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/dnd/cutpaste.html) from the official Java Tutorial. Which, by the way, is the top link for 'copy paste java' in a search engine. What resources were you looking at?

Comment: I found for example :  JTextArea.addMouseListener(MouseEvent eat){ which would then look for the what button has been pressed on the mouse in my case i want the right click which would then activate a JPopupMenu and would have of course ; copy,paste, delete etc. on the JPopupMenu which upon click would activate a method , copy,paste etc.

Comment: @TravJav92 Descendents of `JTextComponent` have a simple `copy` and `paste` method, which is typically tied to key bindings, which you can re-use as menu items by extracting the associated `Action`

Comment: please see update above in my question regarding code, thank you.